# How to include my user as a member in a Group type identity in Sandbox?

Tags: api, platform-of-trust

In [Sandbox](https://world-sandbox.oftrust.net/), the logged-in user needs to be a member of a `group` to register `data products` or `apps`.

How can I add my user to a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, as user, are an identity of type `Person`. A `Group` is also a type of identity in Platform of Trust.

A Person must be linked to a Group with `MemberOf` type of link.

Using `Identity API`, you can create a `Group` type identity and connect your own user identity to the group with a `MemberOf` type link.

To create a group, run the following cURL command:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9eyJzY29w...DVs5aaf" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d \
"{
  "context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/Group/",
  "type": "Group",
  "data": {
    "name": "Company Oy"
  }
}" "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1"
```

On Success, you'll get the following response including the ID of the created `group`.

Next, you need to link your user identity to the created group identity with a `MemberOf` type link.

option1: This post in StackOverflow discusses how to obtain the current logged-in user's ID.

OR,

option2:
Start with getting your user ID (you need to be logged-in into the Sandbox) using `/me` end
point of `Login API`

Request:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi...hdEsJLNGV2YA" \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/me"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200

{
    "@context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/LegalParty/Person/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "33237067-14c3-4801-9e50-bf08406406e2",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "role": "developer",
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Bar"
}
```

Then make a POST request to Identity API with Identity IDs of your user and the created group as parameters:

```
curl -i --request POST \
  --url https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/{fromIdentityId}/link/{toIdentityId} \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9eyJzY29w...DVs5aaf' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/Role/MemberOf/",
  "type": "MemberOf"
}'
```

Remember to set the parameters as the following:

`fromIdentityId` = ID of your own user
`toIdentityID` = ID of the created group above.

On success, you should receive the following response:

```
HTTP/1.0 201

{
  "@context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/Role/MemberOf/",
  "@type": "MemberOf",
  "@id": "be7a2c57-03d8-46f4-aaf0-2b1ca118ef5c",
  "from": "8ac7494b-b7bc-4a63-a253-4b9b1887b262",
  "to": "a6b5a74e-bd98-4c9b-9561-932877258833",
  "data": {},
  "metadata": {
    "createdAt": "2019-09-12T09:49:24+00:00",
    "createdBy": "33237067-e72c-4f26-b78b-9f9e234b2e7d",
    "updatedAt": "2019-09-12T09:49:24+00:00",
    "updatedBy": "33237067-e72c-4f26-b78b-9f9e234b2e7d"
  }
}
```

Now you will bee able to use the created group to register data products and apps in Platform of Trust.

Alternatively, you can use [world-sandbox.oftrust.net](https://world-sandbox.oftrust.net) to create your group identity using the UI. Simply save the group ID that appears in the S-alert.

Checkout Identity API documentation [here](https://docs.oftrust.net/#Identity).

You can also use our [Insomnia Workspace](https://developer.oftrust.net/tools/insomnia-workspace/) and [Guide to execute chain request](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/workflow-using-insomnia-workspace/#executing-a-chain-request-to-create-a-group) to create a `Group`.